# Custom NSMenu Item Title is Visible in Cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, menuitem, nsmenu

I want to Create custom NSMenu item .
First I've Created a View for menu item and then later i have set custom view to Menu item.

```
-(void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{  
NSRect fullBounds = [self bounds];
fullBounds.size.height += 4;
[[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:fullBounds] setClip];
[[NSColor blueColor] set];
NSRectFill( fullBounds );
}

CGFloat menuItemHeight = 32;
NSRect viewRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1, menuItemHeight);
NSView *menuItemView = [[FullMenuItemView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
menuItemView.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable;

NSMenuItem *unlockAllMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"UnlockAll" action:@selector(unlockAllMenuItem_Clicked:) keyEquivalent:@""];
[unlockAllMenuItem setView:menuItemView];

unlockAllMenuItem.tag = MenuItemtagUnlockAllMenuItem;
unlockAllMenuItem.target = self;

NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
style.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
unlockAllMenuItem.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:unlockAllMenuItem.title attributes:@{
                                                                                                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName:NSColor.redColor,
                                                                                                                    NSFontAttributeName:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:14.0],
                                                                                                                    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:style,                                                                                                                        }];
[_menu addItem:unlockAllMenuItem];
```

I am getting like this:

[image]

Menu item title is not visible in above image as you can see.
  Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you're using a custom view for a menu item, your view is then responsible for the entire appearance of the item. The system doesn't draw any part of it, anymore. So, the title isn't showing because you are not drawing it in your `-drawRect:` method.